# material ui select component dropdown positioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

for some reason Menuprops attribute is not working for me and i am not able to change position of drop down box. Please see my code i am doing exactly same as discussed on other related questions.

I want the Menuitmes dropdown box to appear just below the select Input Box and same width as the input box.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { IconButton, InputAdornment, OutlinedInput } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    // padding: "10px",
    width: "100%",
  },
  formControl: {
    // minWidth: 120,
    // width: '90%',
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    "& .MuiSelect-select": {
      fontSize: "12px",
      textAlign: "left",
      //padding: "6px 10px",
    },
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      height: "45px",
      borderRadius: "5px",
    },
  },
  placeholderValue: {
    color: "#9F9F9F",
  },
  selectBox: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    background: "#fff",
    borderRadius: "22px",
    padding: "3px",
    textAlign: "center",
    "&:before, &:after,& .MuiSelect-icon": {
      display: "none",
    },
    "& .MuiSelect-select:focus": {
      background: "transparent",
    },
  },
  Icon: {
    color: "#26a0c9",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  inputlabel: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    lineHeight: "1.33",
    color: "#7d7d7d",
    marginBottom: "10px",
    display: "block",
  },
  isRequired: {
    color: "#ff0000",
    marginLeft: "5px",
  },
}));

export default function SelectComp(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { StartIcon } = props;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.handleChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container alignItems="flex-end" className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <label htmlFor={props.name} className={classes.inputlabel}>
          {props.label}
          {props.isRequired ? (
            <span className={classes.isRequired}>*</span>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </label>
        <FormControl
          variant="outlined"
          className={classes.formControl}
          disabled={props.isDisable ? props.isDisable : false}
        >
          <Select
            value={props.value ? props.value : ""}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            // displayEmpty={props.displayEmpty || true}
            className={`${
              props.module === "timeline"
                ? classes.selectEmpty
                : classes.selectBox
            } ${props.className}`}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": props.label }}
            name={props.name}
            startAdornment={
              props.StartIcon ? (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <StartIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )
            }
            MenuProps={{
              anchorOrigin: {
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left"
              },
              getContentAnchorEl: null
            }}
          >
            {!props.value && (
              <MenuItem value={""} className={classes.placeholderValue}>
                {props.placeholder}
              </MenuItem>
            )}
            {props.options &&
              props.options.map((data) => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem value={data.value} key={data.value}>
                    {data.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very hit and trials i was able to find out the problem.
My MenuItems were very large in number without first specifying the min height css property of menuItems material ui was not shifting the select dropdown below the input box.

After after applying min height property to Paper component below the select input i was able to resolve this.

Use

```
 menuPaper: {
    maxHeight: 200
  }
```

For any clarity please comment and ask

Answer (score 0):

use variant="standard" and Select and MenuItem like this :

```
 import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
    import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
    import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';


    <FormControl variant="standard"  required className={classes.formControl}>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="demo-simple-select-standard-label">vesselType</InputLabel>
    
                        <Select
                            defaultValue={formik.values?.vesselType}
                            value={formik.values?.vesselType}
                            // id="grouped-native-select"
                            name="vesselType"
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
    
                            disabled={!formik.values.imoNo || !imo}
                            className="w-100"
                            labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
                            id="demo-simple-select-standard"
                        >
                            <MenuItem  aria-label="None" value=""/>
                            {vesselType.map((option, i) => <MenuItem key={i}
                                                                
   value={option.value}>{option.name}</MenuItem>)}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
```